# Rewrite old PHP-Nuke page links to wordpress links

Tags: wordpress, redirect, url-rewriting

I had been using an old PHP-Nuke site for the last 6+ years and I finally convert over to Wordpress. There are probably 100's of old links posted on other sites out there that I need to redirect to the new ones.

The old links look like this

```
http://www.mysite.com/modules.php?name=NDReviews&op=Story2&reid=387
```

The new links look like this

```
http://www.mysite.com/cooler-master-ceres-400-headphones/2/
```

The two items that change for each old links are the =Story# and the reid=#

The =Story# now needs to point towards the new /#/

while the old reid=# needs to point towards the /new-name-for-review/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you know how to code a simple plugin. This could be the skeleton to start to play:

```
add_action('init', 'flushRewriteRules');
function flushRewriteRules()
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'insertMyRewriteRules');
function insertMyRewriteRules($rules)
{
    $newrules = array();

    // convert:
    // http://www.mysite.com/modules.php?name=NDReviews&op=Story2&reid=387
    // to:
    // http://www.mysite.com/NDReviews/2/

    $newrules['modules.php?name=([^&]*)&op=Story(\d+)&reid=(\d+)'] = 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&p=$matches[2]';

    // or maybe just redirecting Story# to p=# (post id)

    // convert:
    // http://www.mysite.com/modules.php?name=NDReviews&op=Story2&reid=387
    // to:
    // http://www.mysite.com/cooler-master-ceres-400-headphones/2/

    $newrules['modules.php?name=([^&]*)&op=Story(\d+)&reid=(\d+)'] = 'index.php?&p=$matches[2]';

    return $newrules + $rules;
}
```

---

Is just an idea to experiment a possible solution. In any case is totally achievable.